# socat and ioctl in C

Tags: c, ioctl, socat

On Debian 7, i use socat for modem :

```
socat PTY,link=$HOME/dev/vmodem0,raw,echo=0,waitslave,raw 
        EXEC:'"ssh srv-modem socat - /dev/ttyS0,nonblock,raw,echo=0"'
```

and i try to know the dcd of line (language C) :

```
ret = ioctl(fd,TIOCMGET,&dcd);
```

The return of ioctl is -1 and errno=22 (Invalid argument)

Can I use special commands like `TIOCMGET` within socat?

(I've try to use the same code on srv-modem and it is ok)